# What is the safest way to complete String digits with zeros in Java?

Tags: java, string

Let's suppose the following inputs for Java 8 method:

```
String a = "12345678";

String b = "123456";
```

What's the most elegant and safe way to have this as a result?

```
a -> "0012345678";
b -> "0000123456";
```

I want to have a fixed size String variables that are completed with zeros to the left.

Comment: there is a multitude of ways to do so. you ask about an opinion. This is not a forum for this.

Comment: There is a bunch of ways to this ugly and unsafe. I want one maybe already provided by language or some known framework so I can trust.

Comment: is this only for numbers (integers) ? I used to have one util for this for one of my project before.